# Get a Facebook Page's public posts without an auth token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible (using the facebook graph API) to get the last 5 posts made by a [Facebook Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)?

I would like to display this information in an Android app and want to avoid the overhead of using the Facebook Android SDK to avoid showing the "*[App] would like to access your public profile and friend list*" message because it's annoying and inaccurate.

The following call works without an auth token for example: https://graph.facebook.com/nike

But this one doesn't: https://graph.facebook.com/nike/posts

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

I could scrape the HTML off of this page without an auth token but this seems like overkill for such a simple task: https://www.facebook.com/nike/posts

To summarize:

1. Is this really a limitation of the API?
2. Is there a way to suppress the "*[App] would like to access your
   public profile and friend list*" message when acquiring an auth-token with no extra permissions using the Android SDK?
3. Is it perhaps possible using a server-side SDK?

***EDIT***: Looks like the best way to do this is server-side with [a long-lived App Access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really a limitation of the API?

No.

> Is there a way to suppress the "[App] would like to access your public profile and friend list" message when acquiring an auth-token with no extra permissions using the Android SDK?

Yes. If you read the documentation properly ([Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)), its clearly mentioned that any valid access token is required to fetch the details* of the posts of a page. So, you could use the `App access token`, which you could get without any authorization step- from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) or a simple GET request (server-side)-

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

> Is it perhaps possible using a server-side SDK?

Depends on you, how you want to implement.

*Note: Of course, the posts that you can see would be the public posts only (that could be seen even if a user is logged-out); else you might require user authentication with `read_stream` permission.

Comment: Thanks! Your first answer contradicts the others though. Looks like there is no way to do this purely on the client side.

Comment: Not recommended actually, since app credentials are involved.

Comment: Hi, I used the Get request from server side. This is returning the access token in a string format. But Graph Request requires token of type AccessToken. How to proceed witht hat?

Comment: It uses the type string only.