# Getting specific page public posts without user login

Tags: android, facebook

Hey i'm trying to get public post from specific page but i don't want user to login.
and as stated in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449278/get-a-facebook-pages-public-posts-without-an-auth-token) that i can use my app access token for this 
but my problem is how i can add my app token to graph request because `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`
return null and that obvious because the user is not authenticated
so what is the proper way to set the app access Token

this is my code

```
  new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/Page_id/posts",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
                  System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: You should not use your app access token in client-side code.

Comment: Thanks man but how could i achieve this i need to get just public post and i dont need to login

Comment: Then you should do it server-side (because that is the only save place to use an app access token). If you don’t have a server-side component to your app – then make users login to your app before they use it, so you can use their user access token.

Comment: but if we compare this to opening facebook page from browser  can see the page public post so why i can't do same this in mobile side ? sorry @CBroe but i just need to understand this more

Comment: and also in IOS SDK we can set the Access Token as fixed String and it works perfectly

Comment: _“so why i can't do same this in mobile side ?”_ – because viewing content directly on Facebook, and retrieving content via API are two different things. Facebook has _decided_ that such API requests need to use an access token now, period. And that you _can_ embed your app access token in iOS code, doesn’t mean that you _should_ do it. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens: _“Again, for security, app access token should __never__ be hard-coded into client-side code.”_

Comment: ok Thanks @CBroe could u provide ur comment as an answer it could help the others

Comment: i also took a look on this question and even if i the admin of the page they said that this action no more available after 30 may http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages/12308883#12308883

Comment: I can’t see what you are referring to there. That specific answer you linked to does not mention anything in that regard, and in the rest of the discussion I don’t see anything pertaining to this issue either.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use your app access token to request those posts, then you should do it server-side – because that is the only save place to use an app access token.

If you don’t have a server-side component to your app, and want to fetch the posts client-side – then make users login to your app before they use it, so you can use their user access token.